# AdMobFree 4 in Ionic 4 simply does not return Promise object in banner.prepare()

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob

I have been battling this for days. My call to:

```
this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
  .then(() => {
    // banner Ad is ready
    // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

simply does not return any Promise object that the delegate in 'then' is never triggered and the AdMobFree banner never shown. **Nothing** showed up. The string debug has never been updated to "xxx" proving that the execution never reach there.

My project configuration / settings:

I have AdMobFree plugin version 4 after downgrading as version 5 with folder /ngx simply doesn't work for me - it keeps saying "Object is not a function" runtime error.

I downgraded from Ionic 6 to 5 and to 4 just hoping for a better compatibility after so many suggestions had been followed with no success.

The call is from ngOnInit as follows:

```
ngOnInit()
{
const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
  // add your config here
  // for the sake of this example we will just use the test config
  id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111",
  isTesting: true,
  autoShow: true
 };
this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
    .then(() => {
    // banner Ad is ready
    // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

All related plugins have been imported with no error in that source file and also in app.module.ts.

I really need help here. Otherwise my months of work is going to trash and I'm going back to Java native coding for Android. Screw Ionic, screw hybrid coding.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer few days back. Just downgrade Cordova as well. I downgraded many things but forgot that Cordova can be / has to be downgraded also so that everything compatible.